# How to set text below the QToolButton in QT not below the icon

Tags: c++, qt, text, icons, qtoolbutton

I'm using QToolButton and I set the icon.
Now I want Text `"below the QToolButton"`, `"Not below the icon"`.
Is there any way to achieve this in C++,QT in Linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found myself in the same position a while back ago while I was making an application for an embedded Linux system.

I haven't found a straight forward solution (I was searching for a way to achieve it with CSS).

What I ended up doing, was creating a new QWidget (using the designer). Then placing the button in it with a QLabel under it.

Then added a simple static function

```
static void wdgCustomButton::create(const QString iconPath, const QString text)
{
    // create a new button here, create some modification functions for
    // text, image and optionally QStyleSheets.

    // Call those here (pass the arguments)

    // Then return the button
    // pseudo code, (not tested):

    wdgCustomButton button = new wdgCustomButton( /* could pass a parent */ );
    button->setIcon( iconPath ); // function simply calls the ui->button->setIcon
    button->setText( text );     // function simply calls the ui->label->setText 
    return button;
}
```

And then add those new QWidgets to your pannel using code (maybe someone knows how to get it in the default toolbar, but I haven't searched for that myself yet since I never needed it).

```
this->menuButtons[menuBtnsCount] = wdgCustomButton::create( ":/Images/Warning.png", "Delete everything" );            
this->menuButtons[menuBtnsCount]->setGeometry( QRect( /* size and position here */ ) );
this->menuButtons[menuBtnsCount]->show();
```

I hope this might give you an idea to fix it in an easy way!

**Edit:**
I'm sorry, I forgot to add something about the click event. The click event was mainly why I made a QWidget out of it!
I just used the connect function [I belive on the whole button like: connect(this->menuButtons[0], ...]